# Type in Gujarati in ASP.net Textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox

I am developing a website in asp.net using C#.
There is a web page for registration form which contains dropdownlist for laguage option Gujarati and English.
If user select Gujarati language then user is automatically enable to type in gujarati language in all textboxes of the form.
How i can achieve this functionality?

Comment: Are you want to enable 'Gujarati' language keyboard or want to interpret the words which entered by user?

Comment: I want to enable gujarati typing (like type in english) in textboxes automatically.

Comment: Automatic will need you to create a custom control box as i said in my answer

Answer (score 2):

you can create a custom text box - you might would like to try this www.codeproject.com/Articles/301832/Custom-Text-box-Control-that-Switch-keyboard-langu
unless you change the culture of the keyboard its the only option you have , here is another thorough discussion http://forums.asp.net/t/1414525.aspx